How to inject React CSUI in Plasmo by Chrome.scripting.executeScript?
all. I'm currently working on a Chrome extension with Plasmo framework. I hope to manually active the camera component by using chrome.scripting.excuteScript in popup.tsx file. When I click the button, the CSUI script will be manually executed and then request the permission for open the camera. But now, though the .then function is executed, the component is not inject. And when I use the files property of chrome.scripting.executeScript, the console always claims an error, says Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not load file: '~content.tsx'.. No matter how I changed the file path, it always report this error.  How can I make it work?
This is the popup.tsx file:
import { Button } from "antd"
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import CameraComponent from "~contents"
import { checkRecording } from "~storage"
import "~style.css"
import type { RecordType } from "~types"

const IndexPopup = () => {

  const [recordTabText, setRecordTabText] = useState<string>('Tab Recording')
  const [recordScreenText, setRecordScreenText] = useState<string>('Screen Recording')

  const injectCamera = async () => {      
    const tab = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true })
    if (!tab) {
      return
    }
    const tabId = tab[0].id
    await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: { tabId },
      // files: ["../contents/index.tsx"],
      func: CameraComponent,
    }).then(() => console.log('Injected'))
  }

  const updateRecording = async (type: RecordType) => {
    const recordingState = await checkRecording()

    if (recordingState[0] === true) {
    
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        type: 'stop-recording',
      })
    } else {
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        type: 'start-recording',
        recordingType: type,
      })

      injectCamera()
    }

  }

  return (
    <div className="bg-slate-700">
      <Button onClick={() => updateRecording('tab')}>{recordTabText}</Button>
      <Button onClick={() => updateRecording('screen')}>{recordScreenText}</Button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default IndexPopup


And this is the content.tsx file:
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import cssText from "data-text:~style.css"
import { Button } from 'antd'
import type { PlasmoCSConfig } from "plasmo"
import type { PlasmoGetOverlayAnchor } from "plasmo"

export const config: PlasmoCSConfig = {
  matches: ["<all_urls>"],
}

export const getOverlayAnchor: PlasmoGetOverlayAnchor = async () =>
  document.body

export const getStyle = () => {
  const style = document.createElement("style")
  style.textContent = cssText
  return style
}

const CameraComponent = () => {
  const [cameraPermissionsState, setCameraPermissionsState] = useState<PermissionState>(null);
  const [cameraStream, setCameraStream] = useState<MediaStream>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getPermissions = async () => {
      const permissions = await navigator.permissions.query({
        name: "camera"
      });

      setCameraPermissionsState(permissions.state);

      if (permissions.state === "prompt") {
        await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
          audio: true,
          video: true,
        });
        // After user interaction, we re-query permissions to get the updated state
        const updatedPermissions = await navigator.permissions.query({ name: "camera" });
        setCameraPermissionsState(updatedPermissions.state);
      }

      if (permissions.state === "denied") {
        window.alert("Camera permissions denied.");
      }

      if (permissions.state === "granted") {
        startCamera();
      }
    };

    getPermissions();
  }, []);

  const startCamera = async () => {
    try {
      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: false,
        video: true,
      });
      setCameraStream(stream);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Failed to start camera:', err);
      window.alert("Failed to start camera.");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="fixed top-[10px] right-[10px] cursor-move" draggable>
      {cameraStream && (
        <video 
          
          autoPlay
          muted
          ref={(video) => {
            if (video) {
              video.srcObject = cameraStream;
            }
          }}
          className=" w-[200px] overflow-hidden rounded-full -scale-1"
        />
      )}
      {cameraPermissionsState === "prompt" && (
        <button 
          onClick={startCamera}
          className="px-4 py-2 font-bold text-white bg-blue-500 rounded hover:bg-blue-700"
        >
          Allow Camera
        </button>
      )}
      {cameraPermissionsState === "denied" && <p className="text-red-500">Camera Permissions Denied</p>}
      {cameraPermissionsState === "granted" && (
        <div>
          <p className="text-green-500">Camera Active</p>
          <Button className="absolute" type="primary" onClick={() => setCameraStream(null)}>Cancel</Button>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default CameraComponent;

If there is anything unclear, please let me know. Thanks in advance.
